# Use one elasticsearch server of rails application in another rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

My rails application is running using four ec2 instances. When user hit rails application using url, rails application will be serve to the user using any one of four ec2 instance using ELB.

Elasticsearch server is installed on one of the rails server. How i can use same elasticsearch server which is installed on one server for rest of three rails servers also for searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the internal (10.x.x.x) address for connecting to elasticsearch.

`Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(host:'10.x.x.x',port:9200)`

As long as you set your inbound rules right you can connect to your elasticsearch instance from any ec2 host.

Make sure that elasticsearch listens on 10.x.x.x and not only on 127.0.0.1.

put `network.host: _site_` in `elasticsearch.yml`

Comment: Yes i have already open 9200 port in instance on which elasticsearch server is running but where i need to set ips of rest of three instances so those can access ES server? And how to set server public ip instead of localhost?

Comment: Are you using a gem for elasticsearch in rails, which one? And according to elasticsearch docs "Elasticsearch, by default, binds itself to the 0.0.0.0 address"

Comment: Let me explain all. I have one server(54.34.22.1) on which ES server installed. I have ssh into it and when i run 'curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty', it shows me {.....(some text)}. It means ES server is working. I am able to search in my rails application which is running on (54.34.22.1) server. I have other 3 servers of rails application with ips(54.34.22.2,54.34.22.3 and 54.34.22.4). Now what i should do that rest of three server can use ES server of (54.34.22.1) on which ES installed? Thanks. (Yes i am using elasticsearch gem)

Comment: When you ssh to 54.34.22.2 is `curl 54.34.22.1:9200/?pretty` working?

Comment: No. Please help. How to solve all of this. After ssh, its working when i execute 'curl 'localhost:9200/?pretty'

Comment: please check output for `netstat -an |grep 9200` on your ES host, make sure it says 0.0.0.0:9200. Other issue could be that you didn't open port 9200 in your security group

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109144/discussion-between-rick-and-chris).